# QT Creator cannot start ubuntu apps on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

If i create a new project with QT Creator (Ubuntu 16.04)

1. QML App with C++ plugin (cmake)
2. Framework: ubuntu-sdk-15.04.4-qml
3. Desktop
4. Unix-Generator (Desktop) ( CMake works without problems )
5. I start the programm in Qt Creator ( green arrow )
6. A new windows appears, that has a black background. After a few seconds the windows closes. Qt Creator stays open and i can keep working with it.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works.

I made two mistakes:

- The Desktop kit was set to the wrong qt version
- It was executing the testsuite and not the program itself